# Showing a specific message using Django message framework

Tags: python, django

I am trying to only show one message, if it exists. I tried this but it isn't working:

In view:

```
   messages.success(request, "some message", extra_tags="account_activated")
```

In template:

```
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% ifequal message.tag "account_activated" %}
                <p>{{ message }}</p>
            {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

If I remove `{% ifequal message.tag "account_activated" %}` it works.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's `message.tags` and not `message.tag`. Second, `message.tags` will contain all of the tags for the message separated by spaces, and not just the `extra_tags`.

For your example, `message.tags` should equal `'account_activated success'`.

See the source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/messages/storage/base.py#L42).