# How to keep the track of page navigation in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a following requirement:

I am doing a hobby project which deals with Books management in Django.

I have provided the following options:

1. Add a book.
2. Edit details of the book.

I have separate views function for adding a book and editing details of a book.
When I click on the "Add a Book". The add book page will be displayed. Once all details are filled and form is submitted, I am navigating to details page with "Book XYZ added successfully" message on top of the Details page.

And In main I am having a datatable which displays the books. When the user clicks on any book , the Details page is displayed without displaying "Book XYZ added successfully" on the details page.

My problem is displaying the "Book XYZ added successfully". This message should be displayed only I navigate from add page to details page.
How do I know I navigated from add page from details page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally use the 'messages' framework for this. See the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

This way you can send different messages. For example one for 'succesfully added' and one for 'succesfully edited' that can than be shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Its working. But there is problem. After successfully adding a book, I gave `messages.success(request, 'Book Added successfully')` . But along with it it is displaying other messages also like : Your data saved successfully for many times

Comment: You can set the template to only display messages with specific tags. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452947/showing-a-specific-message-using-django-message-framework

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you could do a query string from add page to details page.

```
// when add page is submitted, and redirect to details page with query string
def details(request):
    added = request.GET.get('added',''):
        if added:
            // renders the page with Book XYZ added successfully
```

Excuse me for the pseudoCode

Comment: Sorry I am new to Django. How Can I add the query string in add page?

Comment: Append '?added=true' to the form's action url. It's just a default HTTP GET query string.